# CheckBox inside Telerik Grid is always Check Even when Value if false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

I am using asp.net MVC 3 Telerik Extension. I have a checkbox inside a telerik grid that is supposed to be checked or unchecked. I noticed that the checkbox value were coming up correctly, they were either true or false. However, the checkboxes are still checked even when checked = "False".

below is a sample code:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.currentStudent).Title("Current Student")
  .Template(
   @<text>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkCurrentStudent" name="chkCurrentStudent" value="@item.currentStudent" checked="@item.currentStudent" />
   </text>
  )
```

The HTML code that is render on the client side:

```
<input name="chkCurrentStudent" id="chkCurrentStudent" type="checkbox" checked="True" value="True">
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some of the answers, I changed the code. Here is how the latest code look now.

```
columns.Bound(o => o.currentStudent).Title("Current Student")
  .Template(
   @<text>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkCurrentStudent" name="chkCurrentStudent" value="@item.currentStudent" @(item.currentStudent=="True" ? "checked=checked": "") />
   </text>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct attributes for checkboxes in HTML is:

For checked boxes:
    checked="checked"

For unchecked boxes, you simply omit the `checked="checked"`

Because you are passing `checked="false"`, your browser is still interpreting the checkbox as checked.  It simply looks for the presence of the attribute `checked` when parsing the HTML.  It doesn't matter what the value of the attribute is...

I added an example at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pqz28/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
columns.Bound(o => o.currentStudent).Title("Current Student")
  .Template(
   @<text>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkCurrentStudent" name="chkCurrentStudent" value="@item.currentStudent" checked="@item.currentStudent" />
   </text>
  )
```

to

```
  columns.Bound(o => o.currentStudent).Title("Current Student")
      .Template(
       @<text>
          <input type="checkbox" id="chkCurrentStudent" name="chkCurrentStudent" value="@item.currentStudent" 
@(item.currentStudent ? Html.Raw(" checked=\"checked\"") : null) />
       </text>
      )
```